# How to put values school year-semester values in dropdown from database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't put the value that I set for school year-semester from database to dropdown.

Here is the code for edit_class_view.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> School Year-Semester:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <?php
            echo form_open('main/editClass');
                $options = array(
                    '' => 'Select School Year and Semester',
                    'SY 2016-2017 2nd Sem' => 'SY 2016-2017 2nd Sem',
                    'SY 2017 Summer' => 'SY 2017 Summer',
                    'SY 2017-2018 1st Sem' => 'SY 2017-2018 1st Sem',
                );
                echo "<div class='drop_pos'>";
                echo form_dropdown('schoolyearsemester', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'required="required"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"', 'value="<?php echo $row->School_Year_Semester;?>"');
            ?>
                <div class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('schoolyearsemester'); ?></div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

If its really codeigniter than you have to get those years from a model store them in an associative array in a controller and then send it to your view. like

```
  public function form()
  {
    $data['years']=$this->school_model->getSemesterYears();
    // Call your view
    $this->load->view('myFormViewame',$data);
  }
```

In your model Create the function like

```
  public function getSemesterYears()
  {
   // Create Query as per your conditions
   $st=$this->db->select('*')->from('tableName')->get()->result_array();
   return $st;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form_dropdown('schoolyearsemester', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'required="required"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"', 'value="<?php echo $row->School_Year_Semester;?>"');
```

Use this instead of the above.

```
form_dropdown('schoolyearsemester', $options, $row->School_Year_Semester, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'required="required"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"');
```